# Delete folder in IntelliJ without also adding to the Git staging area?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm working on a Kotlin project in IntelliJ, and I'm using the Git plugin as well as [GitToolbox](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox).

I'm not sure which plugin is causing it, but whenever I delete a folder in my project, that deletion change automatically gets added to the Git staging area.

How can I disable this, so the folder is deleted (and its contents) but that change isn't added to the staging area until I add it?

Answer (score 0):

You can check "Enable staging area" under Preferences | Version Control | Git and when you delete a file you will be prompted with a question whether you would like to remove a file from Git.

There is a similar request to disable such behavior:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-76200

Comment: I can't find any Preferences, but I found Settings... | Version Control | Git.  But I don't see any "Enable staging area" there.  I checked for updates but it says nothing is available.  As for the request...I can't say I'm encouraged by the fact that it's 9 years old.

Comment: Could you please clarify what version of IDE are you running? 

Even though the issue is 9 years old you can see that the status is "In progress".

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2 (Community Edition) // 
Build #IC-202.6397.94, built on July 27, 2020 // 
Runtime version: 11.0.7+10-b944.20 amd64 // 
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o. // 
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep // 
Non-Bundled Plugins: zielu.gittoolbox, org.jetbrains.kotlin, some.awesome

Comment: I checked for updates and it told me there weren't any available.

Comment: I guess it was lying to me, and I should use the Toolbox instead.  I'm updating now.  I'll try this setting on the updated version and see if it works.

Comment: Same thing after updating; there's no "Enable staging area" in the Git settings.

Comment: Please check screenshot https://imgur.com/a/WW2h2mr

Comment: My options are rather different, though I see some commonalities.  Also, I'm on Windows 10 rather than a Mac.  Not sure why that should make a difference, but...  Does the Community Edition (or the plugin when used with the Community Edition) not have some of these options?  Your "Enable staging area" is front and center.  I'd see if it if were there.  It ain't.

Comment: @RyanLundy could you please share the exact version that you are running? Do you see "Use non-modal commit interface" under Preferences | Version Control | Commit?

Comment: I thought I shared the exact version I was running in a comment above.

Comment: @RyanLundy I am sorry for the delay. 
This feature has been released in 2020.3 whereas you are running 2020.2 Please download the latest version (2021.1) https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download

Comment: OK, I've updated to 2021.1 and now I can see "Enable staging area."  But it's grayed out because I don't have non-modal commit interface enabled.  (I don't commit through IntelliJ IDEA anyway; I commit through the command line.

Comment: I've tried it with the non-modal commit interface both enabled and disabled.  Unfortunately, it makes no difference; IntelliJ still adds the change to the staging area.